# Is there a way to put My Angular App Behind My Spring Boot App, embedded with tomcat

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

So I have a Spring Boot app, with an Angular Front-end. My plan is to embed Tomcat in the Spring Boot app for routing, reverse proxies, etc. What I want to happen is the user types in the URL, the Spring Boot tomcat server figures out if there is a domain linked to that request and so on, however if the user types in the specified IP and Port it brings up the Admin Panel which is the Angular CLI application which already has injections, and Authentication and session control. I don't want people being routed to the Admin Panel unless that condition is filled. I would like the http request to go to the tomcat server and if the condition is met then it pulls up the Angular App. However, I am not quite sure how one would go about this, is it possible to call the Angular app from the Spring application?

Update:
After hearing some feedback I made a diagram to help explain what I am looking for:
[Routing Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNMQ5.png), so in this a client or user would type in `"https://example.com/"` in their browser, it would first go to angular being the frontend, angular realizes it does not have the example.com resource so it requests just example.com/ from the backend, which knows where the resource is and then injects the html file back into the front end. The only time in which a user would be greeted with the login page I have constructed is if they have typed in the primary IP address of the server, which I would probably end up injecting by some variable from the backend as the front end wouldn't know what the IP is... thats a different issue I would have to solve. Is there a better way to do this? Should I be using React.js instead of angular? so far my application structure is very similar to this github repository: https://github.com/liliumbosniacum/spring-security-angular I have modified it and fixed some of the code and am looking into better ways but this was my starting point. I really hope this clarifies, I am looking for if there is a better way to do this or if this is not how it should be done how should it be done? like just an explanation with a diagram on what a better way would be? and Is Angular the Right front end for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your problem is that you want your Spring boot app to route requests to views created by your Angular program and need some authentication features.
For me, I'd rather divide the project into frontend and backend and use JWT tokens, but for your situations you can have a look on this official [Spring documentation](https://medium.com/@majdasab/integrating-an-angular-project-with-spring-boot-e3a043b7307b). It's a detailed post that integrates Spring boot and Angular, and it also deals with Spring security.

Comment: So I already have a structure like that, I have a gradle project with authentication screen and session tokens and session id's etc. The problem I am trying to figure out how to do is right now when I run the project no matter if someone types in example.com or the IP address it brings them to that login screen, when someone types in an example.com it should not go to the login screen but to the website tied to example.com. so I am trying to figure out the reverse proxy and possibly intercept or route things using an imbedded tomcat server within the backend application part.

Comment: u need to make some public urls that are not applicable for spring security login.